# Datetime difference between 2 columns with datetime/str - Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset - below

```
    Create              Complete
0   2005-01-02 01:15:00 2005-01-05 14:05:00
1   2005-01-06 00:00:00 open
```

I want to get the difference in minutes between the two using the below code. However as the 'complete' column also contains a string value, how can I get pandas to ign

```
df['diff_mins'] = df.Create - df.Complete
```

Comment: try to convert the data type

Answer (score 1):

you can use [pd.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) for example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['2005-01-02 01:15:00', '2005-01-05 14:05:00'], 
    ['2005-01-06 00:00:00', 'open']],
    columns=('Create', 'Complete')
)
```

and then:

```
df['diff_mins'] = (
    pd.to_datetime(df.Create) - pd.to_datetime(df.Complete, errors='coerce')
)
```

to get the value in hours, just implement simple lambda function `lambda x: x.total_seconds() / 60 / 60`:

```
df['diff_mins_hours'] = (
    pd.to_datetime(df.Create) - pd.to_datetime(df.Complete, errors='coerce')
).apply(lambda x: x.total_seconds() / 60 / 60)
```

give you:

```
print(df)
               Create             Complete         diff_mins  diff_mins_hours
0 2005-01-02 01:15:00  2005-01-05 14:05:00 -4 days +11:10:00       -84.833333
1 2005-01-06 00:00:00                 open               NaT              NaN
```

Comment: Thank you, very useful! I've rearrange it and got the value that makes more sense- 

df['diff_mins'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Complete, errors='coerce') - pd.to_datetime(df.Create)

How would i convert the diff_mins column to hours?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do it using `map`. It should look something like this:

```py
import datetime

def get_diff_mins(elem_a, elem_b):
  if (elem_b=='open'):
    elem_b = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
  a = elem_a.replace(' ', '-').replace(':','-').split('-')
  b = elem_b.replace(' ', '-').replace(':','-').split('-')
  # Roughly converts yearly time to mins
  # since month is always considered 30 days
  f = [60*24*30*12, 60*24*30, 60*24, 60, 1, 0]
  mins_a = sum([int(a)*f for a,f in zip(a,f)])
  mins_b = sum([int(b)*f for b,f in zip(b,f)])
  return mins_a-mins_b

df['diff_mins'] = map(get_diff_mins, df.Create, df.Complete)
```